# Android: how to trigger an application globally

Tags: android

I am new to android app develop. I learned some basics of the programming skills about Android, and now I am trying to code an app that will be trigger to be active globally.

By globally, I mean no matter it is under home screen or under a web-browser app, or under any other apps. If I long press the back button, my app will become active (the app will take a screenshot).

So my question is that how can I do this? Both tips about android programming and the very detailed implementation steps are needed.

Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot intercept the back button of any application. The reason for this is because applications can **override** the behavior of the back button under their contextual usage.

Also because you don't control the View (from the perspective of an application) because it belongs to the SystemUI this does **not** allow **YOU** to control its behavior at all when it comes to touch/press event.

What you want is **not** possible within bounds of Android in the Context of an application.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use your application globally means you need to make it as library project and then use it where ever you want.

This is the process in eclipse:

1. **File**->**New**->**Other**
2. Select **Android Project**
3. Select "**Create Project from existing source**"
4. Click "**Browse**..." button and navigate to your library project
5. **Finish** (Now your library project should be in your workspace)
6. Right-click on your project -> **Properties**
7. In **Android**->**Library section** click **Add**
8. select recently added project -> **Ok**
9. that's it!

Now you can use it.

Comment: Sorry, where is johannilsson-android-actionbar\actionbar located? I can't find this project. And why do I need this for my project?

Comment: @hexicn See my edit now. Actually I explained a sample(johannilsson-android-actionbar\actionbar) in place of that you need to replace your project which you want to use it as library.